# Differences between 若者 and 若手

Tags: meaning

I just found the word `若手`, and I'm not sure about its differences with `若者`: according to [these](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/1277485) [two](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/14019602) answers, the former means "beginner", while the latter means "young people", but I found [an example](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%8B%A5%E6%89%8B%20%23sentences) (`その歌手は若手にとても人気がある`, "That singer is very popular with young people") which seems to use `若手` just as "young people". [Weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E8%8B%A5%E6%89%8B) agrees that `若手` can have both meaning. Am I right in saying that `若者` means just "young people", while `若手` can have both meanings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your research is not wrong.

若者 is used to refer to young people in general.
若手 is used to refer to a young member of a group, and is often directly attached to nouns: 若手研究者、若手社員、若手俳優 for example.

It is likely that in context, this sentence is referring to young people of a specific group. With no further context 若手 used like this is strange, and should be replaced with 若者.